# fluent nhiberate Reference key word

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

```
public class CTTypeMap :Enity<CTTypeMap>
{
  public CTTypeMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.ID);
    Map(x => x.createdOn);
    Map(x => x.list_id);
    References(x = x.CtListType).Column("list_id");
  }
}
```

In the above lines of code, the statement `References(x = x.CtType).Column("list_id");` maps the list_id of the entity `CtListType` to the Id column of `CTType`.
I need to Map `list_id` of the entity `CtListType` to the list_id column of `CTType`.
pls let me know.

Comment: Do you want to map both the entity CtListType and the property list_id? Also, another question: Enity is a derived class from ClassMap?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the 'Invalid Index N for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=N' error, you should map the `list_id` property as Readonly, like this:

```
public class CTTypeMap :Enity<CTTypeMap>
{
  public CTTypeMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.ID);
    Map(x => x.createdOn);
    Map(x => x.list_id).Readonly();
    References(x = x.CtListType).Column("list_id");
  }
}
```

This way, you can select both the field and the entity without problem. The disadvantage of this is that you cannot insert nor update through the field list_id.

**UPDATE :** Maybe this is not the right way to achieve it, because you are mapping the same field twice, so I recommend you to check another solution proposed in this [post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-and-invalid-index-n-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-n-error.aspx).